# Getting many errors in C++ header and not sure why

Tags: c++

I'm making a car design program. For this program, we are making a class in a header file, and then we will use that header file in our main program by including the file using #include "name of header".

This is my professors header. This is the code in his header. We were instructed to do the header like he is.

```
/*
Program 14-2 
author - Ray Warren, modified from Language Companion
last updated - 19 July 2013
*/

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CellPhone 
{ 
  private: 
  // Field declarations 
  string manufacturer; 
  string modelNumber; 
  double retailPrice; 

  public: 
  // Constructor 
  CellPhone(string manufact, string modNum, double retail) 
  {
    manufacturer = manufact; 
    modelNumber = modNum; 
    retailPrice = retail; 
  } 

  // Member functions 
  void setManufacturer(string manufact) 
  { 
    manufacturer = manufact; 
  } 

  void setModelNumber(string modNum) 
  { 
    modelNumber = modNum; 
  } 

  void setRetailPrice(double retail) 
  { 
    retailPrice = retail; 
  } 

  string getManufacturer() 
  { 
    return manufacturer; 
  }

  string getModelNumber() 
  { 
    return modelNumber; 
  } 

  double getRetailPrice() 
  {
    return retailPrice; 
  } 
};  //end class
```

This is the program he used the header file in (as you see he included the header file).

```
/*
Program14-2
author - Ray Warren, modified from Language Companion
last updated - 19 July 2013
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "CellPhone.hpp"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  // Create a CellPhone object and initialize its
  // fields with values passed to the constructor.
  CellPhone myPhone("Motorola", "M1000", 199.99);

  // Display the values stored in the fields.
  cout << "The manufacturer is "
  << myPhone.getManufacturer() << endl;
  cout << "The model number is "
  << myPhone.getModelNumber() << endl;
  cout << "The retail price is "
  << myPhone.getRetailPrice() << endl;

  system("Pause");
  return 0;
} //end main
```

This is my header file containing my class.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Car(int ym, string mk)
{
    yearModel=ym;
    make=mk;
    speed=0;
}

void setYearModel(int ym)
{
    yearModel=ym;
}

void setMake (string mk)
{
    make=mk;
}

int returnYearModel()
{
    return yearModel;
}

string returnMake()
{
    return make;
}

int returnSpeed()
{
   return speed;
}

void accelerate()
{
    speed += 5;
}

void brake()
{
```

This is my main program with me attempting to include the header file into my main program. When I tried to compile this, my header file popped up in a new code blocks IDE tab, and gave me this list of errors.

http://prntscr.com/bzu4x5 <--------- list of errors

I have  no idea what I'm doing wrong. From what I see, I copied my professor exactly as he told us to, and I'm still getting errors.

Does anyone have any ideas of what's causing this massive list of errors?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Car header.h"

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the field declarations (see comment in professor's code). Ooh and also the class declaration?

Comment: Your header doesn't declare a class ("Class Car { ... };") and is just a collection of functions.  Compare your header to Prof's header, and carefully note the differences.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Folks: Don't downvote a newbie who just need a little guidance.  This is a well-presented question.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, ecpecially pi tures if cut down text. What the heck is `C:\Users\Ashto...`? How do you propose to derive useful information from it? Find a text log and post in the body of your question as text.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you Ivan and Svaberg and everyone else for contributing. 

I made a silly mistake.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham _"This is a well-presented question"_ I strongly disagree! [MCVE] is required.

Answer (score 2):

Your "header file" contains the definitions of the class member functions.  It should actually be a .cpp file.  What you are missing is a definition of the class itself, and *declarations* of the member functions.

Note that your professor's sample header file defines the member functions inside the class definition.  This is actually poor practise, but he may not have got round to teaching you how do define functions out of line yet.

If you *are* going to define the functions out of line, you will also need to change the functions to some thing like:

```
std::string Car::returnMake()
{
    return make;
}
```

Note: "using namespace std" is also poor practise.  Professional C++ code tends to be explicit, and use the "std::" prefix.  Just get in the habit and save yourself hours of pain.

Comment: Will do! 


This is my first time doing a class program.

Would you know what's causing this error? 

http://prntscr.com/bzunkj

@Martin Bonner

Comment: I wouldn't say that function definitions *should* be in a .cpp file. It's a trade-off between things such as performance (inline optimization) and compile time .

Comment: @hyde

How do you call a member function? I'm not sure if you saw the screenshot I posted in this comment section, but I'm having a hard time calling my accelerate member function to use it in my main code. We were never taught how, so I wonder if you had any ideas? We were simply told to use dot notation (as in make an object like car objectCar() and call the member function from the header file).

Comment: @FBHSIE You should really study some C++ basics, if you need to ask "how to call a member function"... Going through some tutorial should show you how. But in general, if you have a new question, ask a new question (preferably with code and relevant error messages or invalid vs expected ouput etc). Comments aren't a place for new questions here.

Comment: @hyde 

I'll take a look. 

Also, that's what we're learning. We haven't learned how to call member functions until now at the end of the course, but the professor only gave us a pseudo-code to go by.

Comment: @hyde

It won't let me ask a new question for a week because I apparently got too many downvotes on this one. So, may you answer my question about my error here?

Answer (score 2):

You did not actually define a class in you header file. Notice that in your teacher's header file, he has:

```
class Cellphone // -> this is what you do not have
{

    private: 

    // Field declarations 
    string manufacturer; 
    string modelNumber; 
    double retailPrice;

    public:
    //constructor function
    CellPhone(string manufact, string modNum, double retail); 

    // Member functions 
    void setManufacturer(string manufact); 
    void setModelNumber(string modNum); 
    void setRetailPrice(double retail); 
    string getManufacturer(); 
    string getModelNumber(); 
    double getRetailPrice(); 
}
```

You should have you fields and member functions inside your class. Hope that helps